# Local repository as submodule

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Assume I have a repository named `Shared Features` on remote and local.

I want to add this repo to another git repo as a `submodule`, but instead of using the remote one, I want to use the local one (for bandwidth reasons).

So I want to use this local repo as somewhat a proxy between submodule and remote repo. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I would be very much appreciated if you tell me how to do this in SourceTree as well.

---

**Edit:** I think I lack the terminology to make my question clear, so here I draw what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Submodule can be any repository you like, but if you like to add it locally you will need a [supported protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) for that.

In the above link the first described protocol is the `Local protocol` which allow you to `clone` using `path` or `file://`

> ***`Local Protocol`***
>
> The most basic is the Local protocol, in which the remote repository is in another directory on disk.
>
> This is often used if everyone on your team has access to a shared filesystem such as an NFS mount, or in the less likely case that everyone logs in to the same computer.
>
> The latter wouldn’t be ideal, because all your code repository instances would reside on the same computer, making a catastrophic loss much more likely.
>
> If you have a shared mounted filesystem, then you can `clone`, `push` to, and `pull` from a ***`local file-based repository`***.
>
> To `clone` a repository like this or to add one as a remote to an existing project, use the `path` to the repository **as the URL**.
>
> For example, to clone a local repository, you can run something like this:
>
> ```
> git clone /opt/git/project.git
> ```
>
> Or you can do this:
>
> ```
> git clone file:///opt/git/project.git
> ```
>
> **Git operates slightly differently** if you explicitly specify `file://` at the beginning of the URL.
>
> If you just specify the path, Git tries to use hardlinks or directly copy the files it needs.
>
> If you specify `file://`, Git fires up the processes that it normally uses to transfer data over a network which is generally a lot less efficient method of transferring the data.
>
> The main reason to specify the `file://` prefix is if you want a clean copy of the repository with extraneous references or objects left out – generally after an import from another version-control system or something similar (see Git Internals for maintenance tasks). We’ll use the normal path here because doing so is almost always faster.
>
> ***`To add a local repository to an existing Git project, you can run something like this:`***
>
> ```
> git remote add local_proj /opt/git/project.git
> ```
>
> Then, you can push to and pull from that remote as though you were doing so over a network.